# mod_rewrite rewrite url using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, rule

I have searched on google and here for a tutorial to help me rewrite my urls.
I would like somebody to explain what I must write and why.

I have this url:

```
http://iescup.eu/tournaments.php?tourney[id]=1
http://iescup.eu/tournaments.php?tourney[id]=2
http://iescup.eu/tournaments.php?tourney[id]=3
```

and so on

I would like to have this url:

```
http://iescup.eu/#!/tourneys/1
http://iescup.eu/#!/tourneys/2
http://iescup.eu/#!/tourneys/3
```

and so on

Sincerely
Rune Naundrup Dahl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you type `http://iescup.eu/tournaments.php?tourney[id]=1` in your browser's URL address bar. The request `/tournaments.php?tourney[id]=1` gets sent to the server **iescup.eu**. On that server, these rules in the htaccess file in the document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^tourney\[id\]=([0-9]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?tournaments.php$ /#!/tourneys/%1? [L,R=301,NE]
```

The `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable is matched against and the numeric ID is grouped and backreferenced by **%1**. The rule's target has a `?` at the end to remove the query string and the `NE` flag is used so the `#` doesn't get encoded.

The rule redirects the browser to `http://iescup.eu/#!/tourneys/1` thus changing the URL address bar. The browser then sends another request to **iescup.eu**, `/`. Note that the `#!/tourneys/1` fragment *is never sent to the server*. Fragments are client side only and is used to determine how content should be dealt with (also used by javascript).

Comment: Thumbs up, I just have another question. I thought the http://iescup.eu/#!/tourneys/1 was just a display for the url, when I enter that link in my browser it leads me back to the index.php of my website.

Can I fix this somehow?

Comment: @RuneNaundrupDahl it leads you back tothe index because the URI (without the fragment is) `http://iescup.eu/`. I assume there's got to be some javascript somewhere that renders something according to the fragment

Comment: Can you give me an example?